# Why is CSIDL_PERSONAL an integer on this line of code?

Tags: c++

Was going through the Filezilla source code and came to this line:

```
int systemFolders[3] = {CSIDL_PERSONAL, CSIDL_DRIVES, CSIDL_NETWORK};
```

I searched the project and couldn't find these variables being declared as ints.

I looked up CSIDL_PERSONAL and it seems to be some kind of system variable for Windows.

So why are they ints?

Edit: If it's a path variable, why is it a number?

Comment: What do you mean by "why are they ints"?

Comment: You know, even when talking about Windows, a number is an int.

Comment: @Mat I just don't know what it is, why is it an integer?

Comment: @Dani So then I could just as easily ask, why is it a number?

Comment: @Ryan: ask Microsoft? I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you are after. They're numbers used to identify things. (CSIDL == "constant special item ID list".) They're numbers because it's easy for computers to use numbers to index things?

Comment: What did you expect them to be? And why?

Comment: I suggest picking up a good programming book.

Comment: @RedX I don't know, a string? Isn't it a path? Sigh... wish I could think of the right things to ask to understand this, my bad.

Comment: @Ryan I think you are asking "if `CSIDL_PERSONAL` is a system folder (which would be a string), why is it a number?". Mat already explained it: they're numbers used for identifying things, just like enums.

Comment: @Marlon I have a book... Matteo did a good job of answering the question below, everyone in comments kind of jumped all over me. Maybe it's my fault and I could have worded the question better. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)s are numerical identifiers (probably `#define`s, whose type is `int`) used to refer to some particular system folders on Windows.

To get the path/shell location they refer to have to you have to use some shell function, typically [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The CSIDL are used to specify whose special folder you want to get the path; the alternative would be to have a separated function for each special folder, which is cumbersome and quite a waste of code.

It's very important to use such method to retrieve the position of special folders instead of hardcoding them, because the position of many of them can be customized/is different for each user (think e.g. at the Documents folder).

Comment: Thanks. Are the implementations for these in a C++ library file, if so which one? Or are they somehow 'built in' to Windows? I guess what I'm asking is where can I find these #define s? Just trying to learn.

Comment: According to their doc page, they are defined inside `Shlobj.h` (or maybe in some file that `Shlobj.h` includes), which is a header file of the Windows Platform SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows box handy right now, but [MSDN lists them as integer constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  They are probably macros included in `<shlobj.h>` so they would be expanded as integer literals.